# Software to determine relationship between natural numbers

Tags: data-analysis

I am looking for something that could, given a set of natural numbers, find the possible relations between them.

For example, given {2,3,5}, return "All relatively prime; First prime numbers".

Though data mining software might be used for this, I believe it has to be trained to do this, and I would like to avoid this.

The Operating System is not a concern to me.

Comment: For which operating system? Are you willing to pay for it?

Comment: @unor I am not concerned about the OS. Regarding payment, we'll see about that.

Comment: [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](https://oeis.org/) could (partially?) solve your problem. For more details and usage examples look [here](https://oeis.org/wiki/Welcome).

Comment: Is that really possible by analyzing the data? Why are { 2, 3, 5 } not the first 3 items of the formula y = 0.5x²+0,5x+2 (at x=0, 1, 2)?

Comment: Give me n numbers and I'll find a polynomial through all those numbers.